# I am having problem with subset function in my code

Tags: r, subset

I am trying to run this code in which I need to get subset of my data set but whenever I try running the code I get the error:

```
Error in subset.default(., select = c("Fluconazole (16 ug/ml)", "Fluconazole (32 ug/ml)",  : 
  argument "subset" is missing, with no default
```

This is the code I run

```
df.fluco.hmf <- 'Phenotyping.All.scaled2.txt' %>% 
  subset(select = c( 'Fluconazole (16 ug/ml)', 
                     'Fluconazole (32 ug/ml)',
                     'Fluconazole (64 ug/ml)',
                     'HMF (31.7 mM)',
                     'HMF (39.6 mM)',
                     'HMF (47.6 mM)')) %>% 
  as.data.frame()
```

and then I get this with the error message:

```
> df.fluco.hmf <- 'Phenotyping.All.scaled2.txt' %>% 
> +   subset(select = c( 'Fluconazole (16 ug/ml)', 
> +                      'Fluconazole (32 ug/ml)',
> +                      'Fluconazole (64 ug/ml)',
> +                      'HMF (31.7 mM)',
> +                      'HMF (39.6 mM)',
> +                      'HMF (47.6 mM)')) %>% 
> +   as.data.frame()
> 
> Error in subset.default(., select = c("Fluconazole (16 ug/ml)",
> "Fluconazole (32 ug/ml)",  :    argument "subset" is missing, with no
> default
```

Comment: You are using the subset function incorrectly.  It is difficult to provide additional help without a sample of "Phenotyping.All.scaled2.txt", The `%in%` function is what you might be looking for.

Comment: Hi I can provide you with the data but I don't know how to upload file here

Comment: Can I email you the data file or is there any option over here where I can show you the dat. Thank You

Comment: I am unable to do this. Can you explain it a bit. i am actually very new to R so it gets difficult to me to understand

Comment: Maybe start here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example.  I am sure if you are even reading the data in correctly to start.  If necessary take a screen shot a post the data that way to start.  You can always delete the question later.

Comment: You are piping the string "Phenotyping.All.scaled2.txt"  into subset function not a data object